# Efficient way to compare all columns in data table R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have two data tables in R which have the same columns (number, name and order) and an ID as follows:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(ids = c(1, 2, 5), col1 = c("A", "B", "F"), col2 = c("B", "F", "G"))
dt2 <- data.table(ids = c(2, 1, 6, 5), col1 = c("B", "A", "K", "L"), col2 = c("F", "G", "M", "G"))

> dt1
   ids col1 col2
1:   1    A    B
2:   2    B    F
3:   5    F    G

> dt2
   ids col1 col2
1:   2    B    F
2:   1    A    G
3:   6    K    M
4:   5    L    G
```

I would like to know for every column how many (common) ids have the same value. For example for col1 we have: for ID1 both values are A, for ID2 both values are B and for ID5 the values differ, therefore the end result for this column is 2.
What I have is the following solution:

```
joint_dt <- merge(dt1, dt2, by = "ids", suffixes = c("", "_old"))
comp_res <- mapply(function(x, y) sum(x == y), joint_dt[, 2:ncol(dt1)], joint_dt[, (ncol(dt1) + 1):ncol(joint_dt)])  

> comp_res
col1 col2 
   2    2
```

Is this the best way to do what I want or am I missing some package or function more designated for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another method is to use inner join to achieve the result:

```
sapply(c(col1="col1",col2="col2"), function(x) dt1[dt2, on=c("ids", x), nomatch=0L, .N])
```

output:

```
col1 col2 
   2    2
```

---

here is a sample data if anyone is interested to time the codes (no `tidyverse` here to time)

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
nr <- 1e6L
nc <- 2L
nids <- nr/100
dt1 <- as.data.table(matrix(sample(nids, nr*nc, replace=TRUE), ncol=nc))[, ids := 1:nr]
setnames(dt1, names(dt1), gsub("^V", "col", names(dt1)))
dt2 <- as.data.table(matrix(sample(nids, nr*nc, replace=TRUE), ncol=nc))[, ids := 1:nr]
setnames(dt2, names(dt2), gsub("^V", "col", names(dt2)))
```

---

some timings for `data.table` solutions:

timing code:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
    mtd0={
            cols <- structure(paste0("col", seq_len(nc)), names=paste0("col", seq_len(nc)))
            sapply(cols, function(x) dt1[dt2, on=c("ids", x), nomatch=0L, .N])
        },
    mtd1=melt(dt1, id.vars = "ids")[ melt(dt2, id.vars = "ids"), ids2 := i.ids, on = .(variable, value)][
        !is.na(ids2), .N, by = variable],
    times=3L)
```

timings:

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 mtd0  179.4386  186.3906  195.6833  193.3425  203.8057  214.2689     3  a 
 mtd1 8306.7968 8373.2351 8467.4561 8439.6734 8547.7858 8655.8982     3   b
```

Comment: The only issue I have with the join is that if the column types are different then this throws an error. It happens when for example a character column is empty in one of my files and fread defaults it to logical while in the other it has some values and it is a character. Any workarounds in mind? Potentially, reading all the columns as character in the fread I guess...

Answer (score 1):

An approach using a join on molten data.tables

```
melt(dt1, id.vars = "ids")[ melt(dt2, id.vars = "ids"), ids2 := i.ids, on = .(variable, value)][!is.na(ids2), .N, by = variable][]

   variable N
1:     col1 2
2:     col2 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table(ids = c(1, 2, 5), col1 = c("A", "B", "F"), col2 = c("B", "F", "G"))
dt2 <- data.table(ids = c(2, 1, 6, 5), col1 = c("B", "A", "K", "L"), col2 = c("F", "G", "M", "G"))

dt1 %>% gather(col,value1,-ids) %>%                                   # reshape dt1
  inner_join(dt2 %>% gather(col,value2,-ids), by=c("ids","col")) %>%  # reshape dt2 and join
  group_by(col) %>%                                                   # for each col value
  summarise(res = sum(value1 == value2))                              # count matches

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#    col    res
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 col1      2
# 2 col2      2
```

Answer (score 0):

One `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
dt2 %>%
 inner_join(dt1, by = c("ids" = "ids")) %>%
 gather(var, val, -ids) %>%
 separate(var, c("var", "temp")) %>%
 count(ids, var, val) %>%
 group_by(var) %>%
 summarise(n = length(n[n > 1])) %>%
 ungroup()

  var       n
  <chr> <int>
1 col1      2
2 col2      2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `map` from `purrr` is perfect for this in combination with the filtering join `semi_join` from `dplyr` that returns rows that exist in both df.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map_dfc(c("col1", "col2"),
        ~dt1 %>% 
          semi_join(dt2 %>% select("ids", .x)) %>% 
          summarise(!!.x := n()))
```

**Result**

```
  col1 col2
1    2    2
```